# Good practice GCE + Windows: computer name

Tags: windows, jenkins, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, perforce

I have some Windows Server 2016 instances on GCE (for Jenkins agents).

I'm wondering what is the best/good practice when it comes to computer name.

Currently, when I want to create a new node, I clone an instance (create images from disks + create template + create instance from template).

On this clone, I change the computer name (in Windows) so that it has the same name as on GCE. Is it useful? recommended? bad? needed?

I know that the name of the Jenkins node needs to be the same as the name of the GCE instance (to be picked up easily). However, I don't think the Windows computer name matters.

So, should I pick an identical generic name for all of them? A prefix+random generated name? Continue with the instance=computer=node name?

The node name that I use in Jenkins is always retrieved from `env.NODE_NAME` (when needed), so that *should* not break any pipeline. Not sure thought, as I may be missing something (internal to Jenkins).

**Bonus question:** After cloning, I have to do some modifications on the clone for Perforce (p4) to work.

- I temporarily set some env variables
- I duplicate the workspace: `p4 client -t prefix-buildX-suffix prefix-buildY-suffix`
- I setup the stream (not sure if doable in one step)
- Then regenerate the list of files: `p4 sync -k <root_folder_to_be_generated>/...@YYYY/MM/DD`

So, here also there's a name `prefix-buildY-suffix` which is the same as the one from the instance=computer=node (`buildY`). It may be a separate question, but as it's still from the same context, I'm putting it here: should I recreate a new workspace all the time? Knowing that it's on several machines, I'd say yes. Otherwise, I "imagine" that p4 would have contradictory information about the state of this workspace. So, here also, I currently need to customize the name. So, even if I make the Windows computer name generic, I would still need to customize the p4 workspace name, wouldn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins must have the same computer name as the one on the network.

So, all three names must be identical.